# Android studio - timer

Tags: java, android, xml

I was just practicing with Android Studio, and I decided to use the `TimePicker` in the palette.

I added it to my XML layout but when I want to reference it in my `MainActivity.java`, it gives me an error and no, I haven't misspelled the id. Can someone explain how this works? Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TimePicker timePicker1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Heres when I tried to reference it 
        timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.layout.timePicker);
    }
}
```

Comment: `it gives me an error` What error? Please post the error message. Thanks.

Comment: You can post your xml file and the error you got, pls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.**id**.timePicker);
```

assuming timePicker is the id of your timepicker. You should double check it. However, the reference inside findViewById will be R.id.****. that's a must.

This is your problem.
Peace.

Comment: i cant believe im making these kind of mistakes... *sigh* 
thank you

Comment: @KardoKamal, anytime

Comment: @kardoKamal also accept the answer